# Missing Content-length in my request header when I use ajax PUT method to send a file

Tags: http, jquery, put

I have a problem regarding `ajax` PUT method.
 When I send a file whose size over approximate 1M, there will be no response for missing content-length header field.
 The 
request header just like this：

```
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://xxxxxxxxxx
Referer:http://xxxxxx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)         
Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

My codes about ajax request as follows：

```
var file = ev.dataTransfer.files[0];
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    processData:false,
    data: file,
    type: 'PUT',
    success : function(){},
    error : function(){}
});
```

The problem happened both in Chrome and Firefox, I don't know how to deal with it. Is it related with Browsers or PUT method?

Comment: Should data be an instance of FormData ( see MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects )?  You can "append" files to FormData object instances.

Comment: if you have files , you might need contentType: 'multipart/form-data'

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully parse "When I send a file which over approximate 1M, the request will have no response for missing content-length in my request header.".

Is the problem that the request doesn't have a Content-Length header field, and the server rejects the request because of that? That would be a server bug (because the browsers then probably used [chunked encoding](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.3.6.1) instead).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is true that sever rejects the request with no Content-Length header field, But I cannot change the server's codes.  I just want to know why Content-Length disappear.   Is it possible to get it back?